# DateTime Comparison with IF statement not working

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

Am trying to make a comparison of `DateTime` in `xamarin`, but it has failed to work , below is my code:

> When the system date is equal to the time set by users , it Toasts a
>   message

```
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
    string timeset = "11:37".Trim();
    DateTime oDate = DateTime.ParseExact(timeset, "HH:mm", null);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" System Time :  " + dt + " Set Time : " + oDate);
    if (dt==oDate)
    {
        StartService();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it has failed to work" ?

Comment: It doesn't execute SatrtService(), when time set is equal to system time date, it has a toast message in it

Comment: wouldn't you rather want to compare a Timespan?

Comment: whats the toast message - and you do know odate doesnt just hold time right?

Comment: I don't think you should use a `==` doesn't it try to compare the references ? Is the operator overloaded ?

Comment: @Icepickle, how can i compare with TimeSpan , because i want to equate the System.TimeDate with the DateTime set by the user

Comment: @Wndrr, i didnt get you well, you want me to use .Equals()

Comment: Nah, ignore my comments i don't work with dates enough to know how to help you without making a test project. What i said probably made no sense :-)

Comment: man this issue seems easy but tricky , some of you guys down voted my post , but i dont see your answer

Comment: `DateTime.Now` will be like "11:37:05.342444". `oDate` will be like "11:37:00.000000", so they are not equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What might be more helpful is to use the difference between the two times:

```
var diffInSeconds = (dt - oDate).TotalSeconds;
```

So:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
string timeset = "08:56".Trim();
DateTime oDate = DateTime.ParseExact(timeset, "HH:mm", null);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" System Time :  " + dt + " Set Time : " + oDate);
var diffInSeconds = (dt - oDate).TotalSeconds;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(diffInSeconds);
if (Math.Abs(diffInSeconds) < 60)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Equal");
}
```

This gives the difference to the nearest minute.

There are plenty of examples found via Google.

Comment: thanks @Peter, how can i put diffInSeconds in an IF statement

Comment: See revised answer

Comment: Why do we say Absolute of datediff is less than 60, because still the notification doesn't come, i have set the time , but the system date reached and it didnt compare it with the time set

Comment: You can set it to what you need. That was just a suggestion to allow for nearest time.

Comment: Thanks so much  @Peter